# Проблема со структурой C++

Tags: c++, структуры

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct tr
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    float n;
};

void init(tr, int n)
{
    float p; 
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        p = (tr.x[i] + tr.y[i] + tr.z[i])/2;
        tr.n[i] = sqrt(p*(p - tr.x[i])*(p - tr.y[i])*(p - tr.z[i]));
    }
}
int sqr(tr, float n)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (tr.n[i] > max)
            max = tr.n[i];
    }
    return max;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    tr triangle;
    init(triangle, n);
    cout << sqr(triangle, n);
}
```

Вот код, не понимаю что делать с этими ошибками.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: С любыми ошибками делают одно - **исправляют**. Тем паче что компилятор ясно пишет, в чем суть ошибки. Например, что такое `tr` у вас в `int sqr(tr, float n)`? Это строка, целое число, дробь, функтор? Нет, это *тип*! И как вы хотите использовать его как переменную? `tr.n[i]`? Да еще и как массив - хотя никакого массива у вас нет... Такие *простейшие синтаксические* ошибки вы обязаны исправлять сами...

Comment: Я передал структуру в функцию, и не понимаю, что он от меня хочет, все же вроде бы правильно написал. Не понимаю зачем вы оставляете "ответ", если не можете мне помочь?

Comment: @Harry все правильно сказал. Если расшифровать, то вы определили структуру, но не объявили переменную, которая будет иметь тип вашей структуры. Почитайте про типы данных,  структуры и т.д. Поймите разницу между определением и объявлением, а затем взгляните на свой код. Ошибка сама бросится в глаза.

Comment: К тому же еще и по ссылке надо передавать переменную в функцию, т.к. вы ее меняете внутри: void init(tr& object, int n) { ... }

Comment: инициализация переменной 'n' как раз таки происходит в функции, поэтому он и называется "init"

Answer (score 1):

```
struct tr
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    float n;
};

void init(tr* triangle, int n)
{
    float p; 
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        p = (triangle[i].x + triangle[i].y + triangle[i].z)/2;
        triangle[i].n = sqrt(p*(p - triangle[i].x)*(p - triangle[i].y)*(p - triangle[i].z));
    }
}
int sqr(struct tr* triangle, int n)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (triangle[i].n > max)
            max = triangle[i].n;
    }
    return max;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    tr triangle[n];
    init(triangle, n);
    cout << sqr(triangle, n);
}
```

Запустилась, вроде бы правильно...